# Ruby on Rails website migration and routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Before the migration, the website was totally ok. Now we have migrated to a new server and the website started showing these kind of error for some links: http://babybum.proj.dev.doo.is/sao-paulo/planta

This is the definition of "area" in fair-controller

```
    def area
       @area_name = BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG.select {|k, v| v == params[:area]}.keys.first
       if @area_name
          @area = Snippet.find_by_identifier([params[:fair_location], @area_name.to_s].join('-'))
       else
          redirect_to root_path
       end
    end
```

The snippet of BB_AREAS_SLUG

```
BB_AREAS = {
:about          => {:link => "quem somos", :slug => "quem-somos"},
:expositors     => {:link => "expositores",:slug => "expositores"},
:map            => {:link => "planta", :slug => "planta"},
:activities     => {:link => "atividades",:slug => "atividades"},
:address        => {:link => "como chegar",:slug => "como-chegar"},
:support        => {:link => "apoio", :slug => "apoio"},
:optin          => {:link => "cadastro",:slug => "cadastro"},
:how_expositors => {:link => "como expor",:slug => "como-expor"},
:press          => {:link => "imprensa",:slug => "imprensa"},
:contact        => {:link => "contato",:slug => "contato"},
}

BB_MENU_AREAS       = BB_AREAS.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v[:link]}
BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG  = BB_AREAS.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v[:slug]}
```

Could someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: `[[:map, "planta"]]:Array` should be a `{map: "planta"}:Hash` maybe you write an own migration to go over these occurences.

Comment: what exactly is line 16?

Comment: Could you paste the contents or snippet of BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG?

Comment: I am assuming that BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG is a hash. can you use `@area_name = BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG.key(params[:area])` instead?

Comment: I edited the post with the snippet of BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propably the problem is another Ruby version. I don't have 1.8 to test it, but propably on old server you have 1.8.x and now is 1.9.x. You need to change

```
@area_name = BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG.select {|k, v| v == params[:area]}.keys.first
```

to

```
@area_name = Hash[BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG.select {|k, v| v == params[:area]}].keys.first
```

or even refractor it to:

```
@area_name = BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG.find { |_, v| v == params[:area] }.first
```

Comment: @ukasz-niemier, the way I'm defining BB_MENU_AREAS and BB_MENU_AREAS_SLUG is giving me a wrong order of the links in the menu (see babybum.proj.dev.doo.is). I want the menu in the exact order as BB_AREAS is defined. It was working in 1.8.x and is not working anymore in 1.9. Could you help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: No. As Hashes in Ruby 1.8.x are unsorted, but you can give a try [`ActiveSupport::OrderedHash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash.html).